# Downloading csv file from bseindia using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to download Results.csv from 'https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Forth_Results.aspx'
I want to basically get data in dataframe format.
I used below code to download the file but it is getting some error data.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
bse_url = 'https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Forth_Results.aspx'
r = requests.get(bse_url)
file_name = Results.csv

with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(): 
        f.write(chunk)
        f.flush()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the help of selenium, follow the below steps:

Step 1: Download the web driver for chrome:

First check your chrome version(Browser's Menu(triple vertical dots) -> Help -> About Google Chrome

Step 2: Download Driver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) according to your chrome browser version(mine is 81.0.4044.138)

Step 3: Once downloaded unzip the file and place *chromedriver.exe* in the directory where your script is.

Step 4: `pip install selenium`

Now use the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import pandas as pd

#your website url
site = 'https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Forth_Results.aspx'

#your driver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe')
#passing website url
driver.get(site)

#wait until whole sites load
time.sleep(5)

#click download icon using xpath
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a/i").click()
#closing browser
driver.close()
#reading Results.csv from defalut download directory
df = pd.read_csv("c:/users/viupadhy/downloads/Results.csv")
df
```

Output:

```
    Security Code   Security Name   Company name    Result Date
0   542579  AGOL    Ashapuri Gold Ornament Ltd  24 Jul 2020
1   500425  AMBUJACEM   AMBUJA CEMENTS LTD. 24 Jul 2020
2   531223  ANJANI  ANJANI SYNTHETICS LTD.-$    24 Jul 2020
3   500820  ASIANPAINT  ASIAN PAINTS LTD.   24 Jul 2020
4   500027  ATUL    ATUL LTD.   24 Jul 2020
5   512063  AYOME   AYOKI MERCANTILE LTD.   24 Jul 2020
6   517246  BCCFUBA BCC FUBA INDIA LTD. 24 Jul 2020
7   540700  BRNL    Bharat Road Network Ltd 24 Jul 2020
8   519600  CCL CCL PRODUCTS (INDIA) LTD.   24 Jul 2020
9   531621  CENTERAC    CENTERAC TECHNOLOGIES LTD.  24 Jul 2020
10  539991  CFEL    Confidence Futuristic Energetech Ltd    24 Jul 2020
11  500110  CHENNPETRO  CHENNAI PETROLEUM CORPORATION LTD.  24 Jul 2020
12  534691  COMCL   COMFORT COMMOTRADE LTD. 24 Jul 2020
13  531216  COMFINTE    COMFORT INTECH LTD.-$   24 Jul 2020
14  526829  CONFIPET    CONFIDENCE PETROLEUM INDIA LTD. 24 Jul 2020
15  506395  COROMANDEL  COROMANDEL INTERNATIONAL LTD.   24 Jul 2020
16  539876  CROMPTON    Crompton Greaves Consumer Electricals Ltd   24 Jul 2020
17  526269  CRSTCHM CRESTCHEM LTD.  24 Jul 2020
18  541546  GAYAHWS Gayatri Highways Ltd    24 Jul 2020
19  500171  GHCL    GHCL LTD.   24 Jul 2020
20  524590  HEMORGANIC  Hemo Organic Limited    24 Jul 2020
21  505725  HINDEVER    HINDUSTAN EVEREST TOOLS LTD.    24 Jul 2020
22  501295  IITL    INDUSTRIAL INVESTMENT TRUST LTD.    24 Jul 2020
23  513295  IMEC    Imec Services Ltd   24 Jul 2020
24  541300  INDINFR IndInfravit Trust   24 Jul 2020
25  500875  ITC ITC LTD.    24 Jul 2020
26  509715  JAYSHREETEA JAY SHREE TEA & INDUSTRIES LTD. 24 Jul 2020
27  500228  JSWSTEEL    JSW STEEL LTD.  24 Jul 2020
28  506184  KANANIIND   KANANI INDUSTRIES LTD.  24 Jul 2020
29  512036  KAPILCO KAPIL COTEX LTD.    24 Jul 2020
... ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: @Ojas Is this what you wanted??

Comment: It seems a bit complicated for simple task

Comment: @UWTDTV np buddy!!

Comment: @VishalUpadhyay Thanks for help.... solution opens required page but not clicking required download file.

Comment: @Ojas I hope you have install selenium using pip(`pip install selenium`), if then also not working, try with Firefox driver, follow instructions from here(https://pycheat.com/download_img.php) and replace the code from my answer's code

Comment: @VishalUpadhyay (probably issue with xpath). As a result it open already manually downloaded Result.csv & throws error if its not there. Can you please look into it. Thanks.
Running code throws error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File c:/users/abcxyz/downloads/Results.csv does not exist: 'c:/users/abcxyz/downloads/Results.csv'

Comment: @Ojas what is your default download directory?

Comment: @vishalupadhyay it is default chrome ‘c:/users/username/downloads’

Comment: @VishalUpadhyay..I made some security changes and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
#PATH CHECK
import pathlib

while 1 == 1 :  # This constructs an infinite loop
    filename='C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Results.csv'
    file = pathlib.Path(filename)
    if file.exists ():
        os.remove('C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Results.csv')
    #your website url
    site = 'https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Forth_Results.aspx'

    #your driver path
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe')
    #passing website url
    driver.get(site)
    time.sleep(10)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDownload')))
    
    #click download icon using xpath
    el=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/a/i")
    el.click()
    #elem.click()
    time.sleep(20)
    driver.close()
    if file.exists ():
        break

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/Results.csv")
print(df)
```